# Error: Pass AuthoringPass is not linked to the rendering graph and will be ignored check it's input/output

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am running an AR app through the Xcode beta on a device with the iOS 13 beta. My debug console is flooded with the message : "[SceneKit] Error: Pass AuthoringPass is not linked to the rendering graph and will be ignored check it's input/output." This is happens when I set the debugerOptions to showBoundingBoxes. The errors go away when the line is deleted or the options are changed to anything else.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        sceneView.session.delegate = self


        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

        sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showBoundingBoxes]

    }
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? IOS 13 has been a mess.